# Memcache - PHP- Ubuntu :: cd: /var/lib/memcache: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, php, debian, php5, memcache

I installed memcache  PHP module on Ubuntu 10.04

My Steps:

1. install php5-memcache (http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache)
2. restart apache
3. get phpinfo()

   ```
   memcache
   memcache support    enabled
   Version     3.0.4
   Revision    $Revision: 1.83.2.36 $

   Directive   Local Value Master Value
   memcache.allow_failover 1   1
   memcache.chunk_size 32768   32768
   memcache.compress_threshold 20000   20000
   memcache.default_port   11211   11211
   memcache.hash_function  crc32   crc32
   memcache.hash_strategy  consistent  consistent
   memcache.lock_timeout   15  15
   memcache.max_failover_attempts  20  20
   memcache.protocol   ascii   ascii
   memcache.redundancy 1   1
   memcache.session_redundancy 2   2
   ```
4. try to  find path: /var/lib/memcache (inside memcache.ini) :

   ```
   cd /var/lib/memcache;
   ```

get error:

```
cd: /var/lib/memcache: No such file or directory
```

Why I don't have this directory?

Thanks,

Yosef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on our Ubuntu 10.04 with php5 with memcache support and running memached services there is also no /var/lib/memcache. For me it is not clear why you are looking for this directory at all.

Kind Regards

Stephan

Comment: True. Same here. And why didn't you just run "apt-get install php5-memcache" but used pecl instead?